# How to fix Angular 11 'Option "progress" is deprecated'?

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, angular-builder

I'm missing the percentage progress view while compiling an Angular 11. Usually I did:

`ng serve`

and saw a progress in percent while the code was compiled. Now that percentage view is gone and it's written that `progress` is deprecated:

> Option "progress" is deprecated: Use the "progress" option in the browser builder instead.

The question is now: what does it mean or where I have to place the `progress=true` option now to get back the percentage view?

Comment: Please post the whole code that you're calling for the progress.

Comment: @NeedHelpASAP I've updated some more info.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of `ng serve`, [it states](https://angular.io/cli/serve) that `--progress=true|false` is no longer used (or moved), as you received the error message.

> **Deprecated**: Use the "progress" option in the browser builder instead.

What needs to be done, is that your `angular.json` file needs to be updated to get the percentage shown again. [Derived from a default StackBlitz Angular setup](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxuquk?file=angular.json), it should look like this:

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/demo",
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "progress": true,
      "assets": [
        "src/favicon.ico",
        "src/assets"
      ],
      "styles": [
        "src/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": []
    },
  },
}
```

where `"progress": true,` has been added to the `options` object. It's hard to test this on StackBlitz, so please try it out locally.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I tried it out but unfortunately the percentage view is not shown while compiling